# Upload images from a phone

Tags: android, image, file-upload, flickr

I'm trying to upload an image from my Android phone to Flickr. The image is picked from the gallery. When I run the program nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE)

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            selectedImage = getPath(selectedImageUri);



            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImage);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();



            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);



            bute data1[] = bos.toByteArray();



            Uploder up = flickr.getUploder();



            UploadMetaData uploadMetaData = new UploadMetaData(); 

            uploadMetaData.setTitle(title);    



            up.upload(data1, uploadMetaData);}

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor c = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        int column_index =  c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);


        c.moveToFirst();

        return c.getString(column_index);           

    }
```

Comment: `bute data1[]` and `up.upload(data[], uploadMetaData)` - this will not compile. Are you sure this is the code you're running? If yes, what error do you get?

Comment: Sorry,my mistake. The code i am running is up.upload(data1,uploadMetaData).

Comment: At a glance your code looks Ok, however smth in your `onActivityResult()` is null. You need to debug to find out what exactly is null.